# How to calculate total sales in MongoDB but the product price data comes from different collection

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections in MongoDB, sales and products

[Here is the "sales" collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV7vy.png)

[And here is the "product" collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW5PR.png)

Please help me for the query to calculate the total income / sales :
1. the total income that occurs at Outlet-A.
2. the total income that occurs only at 2018.

Im confuse because the product price data is provided in the "product" collection, while the sales data is in "sales" collection. 
I hope you can help me solve this problem guys. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $lookup to join two collections:

example:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
     $match:{
         Outlet_name: "Outlet-A",
         Sales_date: {$gte: startDate,$lte: endDate}
       }
  },
  {
    $lookup:{
        from:"product",
        localField:"Product_name",
        foreignField: "Product_name",
         as: "products"
    }
  },
  {
      $unwind:"$products"
  },
  {
      $group:{_id:null, totalSales:{$sum:"$products.Product_price"}}
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi Saha,
I just tried it. It works.
I am very happy. Thank you very much for the help.